# Home Screen shortcut name does not change automatically on device language change

Tags: android

I have an application for which I have also created a home screen shortcut from code. My app supports multiple languages. When I change the language on phone, the app name changes properly in launcher screen. But the name does not change for the home screen shortcut. On other hand, if I first change the language and then install the app, the home screen shortcut contains proper name.

As per my similar question in this post :

[Application title for homescreen shortcut does not change on phone language change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061415/application-title-for-homescreen-shortcut-does-not-change-on-phone-language-chan)

people suggested me that it is not possible and so I have handled it explicitly from code. But now I see for some applications on phone, the name is getting changed automatically on device language change. Can someone tell me is it possible or not? If yes, can you give me some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally make it work with the following code:

public void createShortcut() {

```
appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
isAppInstalled = appPreferences.getBoolean("isAppInstalled", false);

 if(!isAppInstalled){

    Intent HomeScreenShortCut= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            BrowserLauncherActivity.class);

    HomeScreenShortCut.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    HomeScreenShortCut.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);   
    HomeScreenShortCut.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    HomeScreenShortCut.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, HomeScreenShortCut);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"); 
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);


    //Make preference true
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isAppInstalled", true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

specifically, This line did the trick:

```
HomeScreenShortCut.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

Hope it helps someone.